# How to give the same link to multiple auto-generated buttons with the same ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to give the same link to multiple auto-generated buttons with the same ID?

I've tried, but it only gives the first button the link, the rest of the buttons remain empty

```
$('#Button').click(function() {
    window.location='aaa.html';
});
```

Comment: You shouldn't have multiple elements with the same id, use a class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In HTML there can be only one element with given ID, to assign the same jQuery code to multiple elements you should use "class" attribute instead.

See: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2

**JS:**

```
$('.button').click(function() {
                    window.location='aaa.html';
                    });
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="button">DIV 1</div>
<div class="button">DIV 2</div>
<div class="button">DIV 3</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

> I've tried, but it only gives the first button the link, the rest of the buttons remain empty

Identifiers should be unique across the page to be valid HTML.

When querying by Id, jQuery will only ever return the first one matched.

Try to use a class instead as classes can apply to groups of elements.

Then you update your selector to use the class indicator `.` instead, similar to this:

```
$('.YourClassName').click(function() {
    window.location='aaa.html';
});
```

---

For more details on the jQuery id selector have a look at the [**ID Selector (“#id”)**](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) documentation.

As stated there as well:

> Each id value must be used only once within a document. If more than
>   one element has been assigned the same ID, queries that use that ID
>   will only select the first matched element in the DOM. This behavior
>   should not be relied on, however; a document with more than one
>   element using the same ID is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't give multiple elements the same `id`, but if you have to, you could use:

```
$('[id="Button"]').click(function() {
    window.location='aaa.html';
});
```

I would suggest making the `id`s all start with "Button" and add an integer to the end when generating them, so you'd have the structure:

```
<div id="Button1"></div>
<div id="Button2"></div>
<div id="Button3"></div>
```

so you could use:

```
$('[id^="Button"]').click(function() {
    window.location='aaa.html';
});
```

Another option is to set a specific `class` instead, and have the following structure:

```
<div class="button-class"</div>
<div class="button-class"></div>
<div class="button-class"></div>
```

and use something like:

```
$('.button-class').click(function() {
    window.location='aaa.html';
});
```

Something you might want to look into is event delegation: http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events

References:

- http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/
- http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

Comment: +1 for `[id^="Button"]` when using enumerated identifiers. Very useful information.

Answer (score 0):

Having multiple identical IDs is against HTML specification. You can use css class or other selectors.